# Implementation of binary search that returns object instead of index?

Tags: java, time-complexity, binary-search

So is it possible to write an implementation of binary search that returns object instead of index? I need that so the whole task is completed in `O(logn)` time and not spend more time by then calling collection.get() after i get just the index so the complexity then becomes `O(nlogn)`.

Comment: Why would calling `get` make the complexity O(nlog(n))?

Comment: What type of collection is it?

Comment: @user2357112 because you parse the collection serially in order to get the object i guess. It's mot like you have a pointer to the item just its index in the collection

Comment: A binary search would require a random-access container.If you know the index, you should be able to reach the item in O(1). If this is not the case, then a binary search would be the wrong algorithm in the first place.

Comment: @Andrew Shepherd it works like a pointer?

Comment: @paulboddington its an arraylist

Comment: Well in that case get is just an array access, so it's O(1).

Comment: It doesn’t work like a pointer, it works like an array. It actually uses an array. That’s why it has been named `ArrayList`.

Comment: @paulboddington oh thanks i didnt really know that i thought it would be more complex i guess.
Thank you all guys!

Comment: can someone make an answer so i can close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A binary search would require a random-access container.If you know the index, you should be able to reach the item in O(1). If this is not the case, then a binary search would be the wrong algorithm in the first place.

In this case, you are using an `ArrayList`, which is a wrapper around an array, which does indeed provide efficient random access.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be doing binary search on anything but an *O(1)* random-access collection: otherwise the search time would be way beyond *O(log(N))*. The so-called 'extra time' is non-existent in an *O(1)* collection: your replacement will have to do the same step anyway.